# Given a filename in C how to read each line for only 75 characters?

Tags: c, fgets

Suppose I have a file that contains the contents below:

```
This line contains more than 75 characters due to the fact that I have made it that long. 
Testingstring1
testingstring2
```

This is my code:

```
void checkLine( char const fileName[]){
    FILE *fp = fopen(fileName,"r");
    char line[75];
    while (1) {
        fgets(line,75,fp);
        if (feof(fp)){
            break;
        } else {
            printf("%s\n", line);
        }
    }
}
```

How do I make it so that it only saves the first 75 characters from each line in the variable `line`?

The code above gives the following output:

```
This line contains more than 75 characters due to the fact that I have mad
e it that long.

Testingstring1

testingstring2
```

The expected output is supposed to be like this:

```
This line contains more than 75 characters due to the fact that I have mad
Teststring1
Teststring2
```

Comment: Note that technically speaking, it is impossible to read only the first 75 character of each line. You still have to read the entire line to find the line terminator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximal strlen will be 74.

```
bool prior_line_ended = true;
while (1) {
    fgets(line, 75, fp);
    if (feof(fp)){
        break;
    }

    // Remove any line end:

    char* pos = strchr(line, '\n');
    //char* pos = strchr(line, '\r');
    //if (pos == NULL) {
    //    pos = strchr(line, '\n');
    //}
    bool line_ended = pos != NULL;
    if (line_ended) {
        *pos = '\0';
    }

    // Output when starting fresh line:

    if (prior_line_ended) {
        printf("%s\n", line);
    }
    prior_line_ended = line_ended;
}
```

Comment: when you say " The maximal strlen will be 74", does that mean I need to declare char line[74]?

Comment: [fgets](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm) in general get passes the size of the passed char array, where the terminating `\0` is included. Hence 75 allows a strlen of 1 less.

Comment: so what do i need to put for char line[?] ?

Comment: `char line[75+1], fgets(... 75+1 ...)`  for lines of length 75

Comment: suppose I need to pass the "line" as a parameter, where would I put the statement at? would it be in the last if statement?

Comment: Yes, the truncated line is where the printf happens. A prior line just ended, so it is not a continuation (we skip)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
// If we read an incomplete line
if(strlen(line) == 74 && line[73] != '\n') {
    // Read until next newline
    int ch; // Yes, should be int and not char
    while((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
        if(ch == '\n') 
            break;
    }
}
```

Put it after your else block.

Here is a complete version that fixes the printouts properly:

```
void checkLine( char const fileName[]){
    FILE *fp = fopen(fileName,"r");
    char line[75];
    while (1) {
        fgets(line,75,fp);
        if (feof(fp)){
            break;
        } else {
            // fgets stores the \n in the string unless ...
            printf("%s", line);
        }

        if(strlen(line) == 74 && line[73] != '\n') {
            // ... unless the string is too long
            printf("\n");
            int ch; 
            while((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
                if(ch == '\n') 
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`if(strlen(line) == 74 && line[73] != '\n')` can be replaced by `if(strchr(line, '\n'))` if you prefer.

And, of course, you should check the return value for `fgets` and `fopen` in cases there is an error.

Comment: I got a segmentation fault 11

Comment: @NeelPatel I did not